# Listing objects inside the directory of bucket

Tags: c#, google-api, google-cloud-storage, bucket

Several days ago, I was working with Google Cloud Storage listing and downloading objects inside buckets but now I am struggling to read only objects inside the specific directory because I want only iterate over the objects inside this directory. My bucket is "pubsite_prod_rev_12345" but I try to read-only elements inside "/earnings/" :

```
 string bucketId = "pubsite_prod_rev_12345/earnings";
```

So now I turn to the help of experts in this matter, this is my code:

```
 string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only" };
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(@"C:\Data\Jorgesys\jorgesys-8aa7ab2343daa.json").CreateScoped(scopes);
            var storage = StorageClient.Create(credential);
      
            var bucket_name = "jorgesys.appspot.com";            
            //string bucketId = "pubsite_prod_rev_12345";

            //Trying to make a list only inside earnings directoy!
            string bucketId = "pubsite_prod_rev_12345/earnings";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                var bucketObjects = storage.ListObjects(bucketId);
                foreach (var bucketObject in bucketObjects)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine("Object Name: " + bucketObject.Name);
                    sb.AppendLine("Id: " + bucketObject.Id);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {             
                sb.AppendLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
```

I don´t want to filter, just get the elements inside `/earnings/` directory, how could achieve this task.

```
> miroslava/earnings_202102_2138916436889858-1.zip
> miroslava/earnings_202103_2138916436889858-2.zip
> miroslava/earnings_202104_2138916436889858-3.zip
> miroslava/earnings_202105_2138916436889858-4.zip
> earning/earnings_202102_2138916436889858-1.zip
> earnings/earnings_202103_2138916436889858-2.zip
> earnings/earnings_202104_2138916436889858-3.zip
> earnings/earnings_202105_2138916436889858-4.zip
> financial-stats/subscriptions/subscriptions_com.jorgesys_mensual1_201607_country.csv
> financial-stats/subscriptions/subscriptions_com.jorgesys_mensual1_201607_device.csv
> financial-stats/subscriptions/subscriptions_com.jorgesys_mensual1_201607_country.csv
> financial-stats/subscriptions/subscriptions_com.jorgesys_week1_201607_device.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage does not have directories. The directory portion of the ***filename*** is called a **prefix**.

For example the object name: **tmp/log.txt** has the prefix **tmp/**.

The next concept is the **delimiter**. This is typically the **/** character.

To specify the directory path **tmp** use a prefix of **tmp/** and a delimiter of **/**. Any objects that start with **tmp/** and do not contain the delimiter (excluding the prefix) are returned as names. Any objects that start with **tmp/** and contain a delimiter are returned as prefixes. Example **tmp/subdirectory/123** would be returned as the prefix **tmp/subdirectory/** with nothing additional as a name.

With that complicated explanation here is an example:

Note: Your line with **bucketId** is not correct. The bucket name does not include any part of the object name.

```
var bucketName = "pubsite_prod_rev_12345";

// Specify the delimter.
var delimeter = "/";

// Specify the prefix
var prefix = "earnings/";

var storage = StorageClient.Create();

var options = new ListObjectsOptions { Delimiter = delimiter };

var storageObjects = storage.ListObjects(bucketName, prefix, options);

foreach (var storageObject in storageObjects)
{
    sb.AppendLine("Object Name: " + storageObject.Name);
}
```

[Class StorageClient](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient)

[Class ListObjectOptions](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.ListObjectsOptions)

Comment: Thank you John!, I must stop being lazy, what you indicate in fact comes in the comments of the example in C# to list objects inside the bucket!: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-csharp